# How to change .from in UITransitionContextViewControllerKey

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I have some issue with this animation :

```
fileprivate var rootKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey 
{
  return presenting ? .from : .to
}

fileprivate func root(from context: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) -> ElongationViewController 
{
let viewController = context.viewController(forKey: rootKey)
if let navi = viewController as? UINavigationController 
{
  for case let elongationViewController as ElongationViewController in navi.viewControllers 
  {
    return elongationViewController
  }
} else if let elongationViewController = viewController as? ElongationViewController 
{
  return elongationViewController
}

fatalError("Can't get `ElongationViewController` from UINavigationController nor from context's viewController itself.")
}
```

**I always go to the fatalError except when my ViewController is the Initial View Controller.**

I think it's because of .from in rotKey, how can i change .from to my actual ViewController ?